# If $\omega$ is an imaginary fifth root of unity, then $\log_2 \begin{vmatrix} 1+\omega +\omega^2+\omega^3 -\frac{1}{\omega} \\ \end{vmatrix}$ =

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> If $\omega$ is an imaginary fifth root of unity, then $$\log_2 \begin{vmatrix}
> 1+\omega +\omega^2+\omega^3 -\frac{1}{\omega} \\
> \end{vmatrix} =$$

My approach :

$$\omega^5 = 1 \\ \implies 1+\omega +\omega^2 +\omega^3 + \omega^4 =0$$

Therefore, \begin{align}\log_2 |1+\omega +\omega^2+ \omega^3 -\frac{1}{\omega}| &=\log_2 |1+\omega +\omega^2+ \omega^3 -\omega^4|\\& =\log_2|-2\omega^4|\\ &=\log_2 2 +\log_2 \omega^4 \end{align}

Now how to solve further; please suggest.

Comment: You forgot to take the modulus for the argument of the last logarithm. That makes things pretty easy.

Comment: can you elaborate @DanielFischer

Comment: You get $$\log_2 \lvert -2\omega^4\rvert = \log_2 2 + \log_2 \lvert \omega^4\rvert.$$ What is $\lvert \omega^4\rvert$?

Comment: is it unity.... guessing as per the answer given is 1..

Comment: If $\rho^k = 1$ for some $k > 0$, what is $\lvert\rho\rvert$?

Comment: I suppose you mean *nonreal* fifth root of unity; there are no imaginary fifth roots of unity.

Comment: Use the **BIG** hints given by @DanielFischer - you know that all the roots of unity must have a magnitude of exactly $1$

Answer (score 4):

Since
$$
\begin{align}
1+\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3+\omega^4
&=\frac{1-\omega^5}{1-\omega}\\[3pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$
we have
$$
\begin{align}
1+\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3-\frac1\omega
&=-\omega^4-\frac1\omega\\
&=-\frac{\omega^5+1}\omega\\
&=-\frac2\omega
\end{align}
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
\log_2\left|1+\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3-\frac1\omega\right|
&=\log_2\left|-\frac2\omega\right|\\
&=\log_2(2)\\[6pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

$$\omega^5=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\omega^5=e^{0i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\omega=\left(e^{2\pi ki}\right)^{\frac{1}{5}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\omega=e^{\frac{2\pi ki}{5}}$$

With $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $k:0-4$

---

So, the solutions are:

$$\omega_0=e^{\frac{2\pi\cdot0i}{5}}=e^{\frac{0}{5}}=e^0=1$$
$$\omega_1=e^{\frac{2\pi\cdot1i}{5}}=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}$$
$$\omega_2=e^{\frac{2\pi\cdot2i}{5}}=e^{\frac{4\pi i}{5}}=e^{\frac{4\pi i}{5}}$$
$$\omega_3=e^{\frac{2\pi\cdot3i}{5}}=e^{\frac{6\pi i}{5}}=e^{-\frac{4\pi i}{5}}$$
$$\omega_4=e^{\frac{2\pi\cdot4i}{5}}=e^{\frac{8\pi i}{5}}=e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{5}}$$

So:

$$\omega=
\begin{cases}
1\\
e^{\pm\frac{2\pi i}{5}}\\
e^{\pm\frac{4\pi i}{5}}
\end{cases}$$

---

---

- When $\omega=1$:
  $$\log_2\left|1+1+1^2+1^3-\frac{1}{1}\right|=\log_2\left|1+1+1+1-1\right|=\log_2\left|3\right|=\log_2(3)$$
- When $\omega=e^{\pm\frac{2\pi i}{5}}$:
  $$\log_2\left|1+e^{\pm\frac{2\pi i}{5}}+\left(e^{\pm\frac{2\pi i}{5}}\right)^2+\left(e^{\pm\frac{2\pi i}{5}}\right)^3-\frac{1}{e^{\pm\frac{2\pi i}{5}}}\right|=1$$
- When $\omega=e^{\pm\frac{4\pi i}{5}}$:
  $$\log_2\left|1+e^{\pm\frac{4\pi i}{5}}+\left(e^{\pm\frac{4\pi i}{5}}\right)^2+\left(e^{\pm\frac{4\pi i}{5}}\right)^3-\frac{1}{e^{\pm\frac{4\pi i}{5}}}\right|=1$$

Comment: The OP didn't ask what the fifth roots of unity are.

Comment: @DanielFischer I know, but I was'nt finished in my answer

Comment: You do not need to evaluate the actual fifth roots of unity to solve this. The OP was working along the right lines and is just one step away from the answer.

Comment: I read OP's approach and found it quite elegant but couldn't understand how anything could be done further for a logarithm of an imaginary quantity. I was struck with wonder when I saw how you reduced it to a function of e, who's logarithm could be computed. Well done !

Comment: @user230452 Except that this does not even allow to answer the question. As often with this OP, we are fed with irrelevant stuff (everything before "When $\omega=1$"), then the conclusion is asserted as if by magic, but the steps necessary to reach it are not there! In the present case, why should we take the fact that $$\left|1+e^{\pm\frac{2\pi i}{5}}+\left(e^{\pm\frac{2\pi i}{5}}\right)^2+\left(e^{\pm\frac{2\pi i}{5}}\right)^3-\frac{1}{e^{\pm\frac{2\pi i}{5}}}\right|=2$$ for granted/obvious/easy to see? The whole answer is written as a tightly-knit proof but this is all a deception.